# Kentico Form - Edit Form Action and Field Names

Tags: kentico

I have a form built in Kentico and want to change the form action to point to a marketing automation vendor website (eloqua) to process the form. I noticed that there's no way to change the Action on the Form app, so I thought of using js to replace the action dynamically. I'm not sure whether it'll work, but another immediate problem I have is the field name/id generated by Kentico is so long (> 70 characters - e.g. `p$lt$ctl02$pageplaceholder$p$lt$ctl03$On_lineForm$viewBiz$Company$txtText`) and exceeds the length allowed by the vendor. Is there a way to shorten those names/ids?

To clarify, the reason I need to edit the name because the vendor allows to map (copy/paste) html name to whatever name it's using. I've tried pasting the whole string from one Kentico field and got the error message of exceeding character limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First part of the question, how do i direct a form to submit to another site?

In ASP.Net, the only way is to use javascript to alter the 's action url.  Since you want to be careful where you edit this, i would use jQuery to replace the "Submit" button on your form with a javascript function that will alter the form before submission (so you don't mess up other postbacks)

```
$("button.MySubmitButton").click(function() {
   $("form").attr("action", "http://TheVendor.com/PostLocation");
});
```

Next question is to alter the field names.  If you absolutely MUST have form element IDs sub 70 characters, you will have to use Javascript again and it will break any postback-related functionality of the elements, so make sure the form is "as is" before doing it.

Again there is security concern because when you post to another location, you are sending ALL the data, including hidden asp.net inputs that contain viewstates and the like.  You may want to take the time to 'eliminate' right before you submit any field that you don't want sent to the other site.

Something like this (Test it out a bit first though)

```
$("input:not(id*='txtName'):not(id*='txtEmail'),select:not(id*='ddlQuestion')").remove();
```

Comment: thanks! Although not 100% answered the question, I think I can get it from here!

Answer (score 1):

As @trevor-j-fayas points out, you can use javascript to point a form action to another url. While this does work you may end up writing a lot of javascript to not only point the form to a new url but also to do some data massaging (changing id's, doing url formatting, etc) before sending it to the target.

Additionally you lose some of the benefits of using a Kentico Form because the data never actually gets submitted back to Kentico such as email alerts.

I have worked in a similar scenario where were we sending data to Eloqua but instead of doing it client side we did it from the server by using either:

- The `OnOnAfterSave` event on the BizForm control itself
- The global BizForm submit hook `BizFormInfo.TYPEINFO.Events.Insert.After`

After the form is submitted to Kentico, our custom hook code runs which sends the data to Eloqua. In either hook you can fully access the Form metadata, field names, and submitted values. You can then craft an HTTP POST request and submit it asynchronously using a class such as `HttpClient`.

Comment: I'll dig more into what you suggested. It's good to know you've done it and it worked. I currently only have access to the Portal Engine (admin area) but not the server. Can this be done with that level of access?

Comment: @Michelle you do not need direct access to the physical server in order to implement this solution but you will need to be able to write custom .Net code and have that code deployed to the server. This [Kentico 9](https://docs.kentico.com/k9/custom-development/handling-global-events/handling-object-events) KB article outlines how to implement global hooks (which you can only do in code).

Answer (score 0):

Is not a good idea from the architecture stand point and most likely not going to work without opening a huge hole in their vendor web site security. First of all how  are they going to process the from if they don't know the field names, what if form fields change etc. Secondly you going to run into hell of trouble trying to submit form one site to another etc. What if the vendor site is not responding etc.
What you need to do is submit the form back to kentico web site i.e. process it on kentico web site and send email notification with results to marketing automation vendor website (the easy way for now) and redirect user to vendor web site.

Redirection and email - you can do out of the box without any programming. Actually to do all the above requires no programming and you get all the information recorded on your Kentico site.

Comment: I do understand you meant. I did create a couple Kentico forms myself and saw they work very nicely. The thing is for other forms they need to tie the form to the marketing automation vendor. And marketing automation is not just about storing form/people's info, it also does a lot  a lot more stuff such as sending out automatic emails if the user's behaviors hit certain predefined landmarks etc. I guess, I just use iframe, if worst comes to worst